Profiling GraphQL Queries
I have a codebase written with nextjs, urql, prisma, graphql yoga and postgres. There are some slow queries I need to make faster.
What is the recommended approach for query profiling?
Ideally I would want a tree structure for resolvers like you have for call trees when doing performance profiling.

Apollo Studio has some great resources for query profiling.
